Tailwind gives me problems after running the project
1
I'm facing an issue when trying to use Tailwind CSS in my React (or Next.js, if applicable) project. The app loads and works for a few seconds, but then displays the following error in the console:
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (1:0) You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
@tailwind base; | | @tailwind components;
Context: I'm using Webpack as a bundler (or Next.js, if applicable). I've already installed Tailwind CSS and its dependencies according to the official documentation. My tailwind.config.js file is configured correctly. This is my postcss.config.js file:
module.exports = {
  plugins: {
    tailwindcss: {},
    autoprefixer: {},
  },
};

What I tried: 1.I verified that the dependencies are installed: npm install tailwindcss postcss autoprefixer 2.I verified that postcss.config.js and tailwind.config.js are in the root directory. **Additional detail: **The app loads fine and works for a few seconds before throwing the error. During those initial seconds, everything seems to be working, but then it stops responding and the error mentioned appears. **Question: **What could be causing the error to occur after a while and not at startup? Is it a problem with Webpack configuration, PostCSS, or something else? Thanks in advance!

This is a Q&A site; you should ask the question in the title, not treat it like a forum post. As you wrote it, people who know the answer might just skim past it as they scroll through 100 more specific questions.

Follow this nextjs guide by tailwindcss.
https://tailwindcss.com/docs/guides/nextjs

What does your CSS look like?  Is it literally:
@tailwind base; | | @tailwind components;

If so, try putting them on separate lines
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;

